# shrinkResources true can't be used on Instant Apps Feature?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

When I try to shrink my Feature APK size, I use `shrinkResources true` in my feature Build Gradle.
However it complaints `Error:Resource shrinker cannot be used for libraries.`

This article ask us to use it
https://medium.com/jet-stories/make-your-app-instant-33855ab5d02b

Did I do something wrong or is this really not supported by Instant Apps?

Comment: This might be a possible issue in the recent Gradle versions.  `shrinkResources` works fine for me on AS 3.0 Canary 4. But when I tried to use `shrinkResources true` in AS 3 beta 4, I got the same error as you do. Can you file a bug, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: Thanks. Filed on https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Comment: @Elye Can you share the link to the issue? I'm unable to find it https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:316045%20shrinkResources nor https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:316045 Thanks!

Comment: Ops, there you go. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65708840

Comment: Disappointed that AS3.0 has been officially released, yet ShrinkResources is still not usable for IA :(

Answer (score 9):

From what I understand from the article (I've just read it quickly, still pending in my reading list), `shrinkResources true` is only needed to reduce APK size by [removing unused resources](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources), but it is not a formal requirement of Instant Apps. I guess the toolchain cannot decide if a resource will be unused in a library, as final APK is not built.

So, if there are no unused resources in your project, should not be a problem and could be removed.

Then, there is one thing that maybe is wrong in your project (without having tried Instant Apps by myself, just read and saw Google IO talks): from what I understand, all the modules of an instant app are APKs, not libraries. So, if you apply the `shrinkResources true` to the APKs, you should be good to go. If you have libraries in your project that are used to assemble the final APK modules, then remove `shrinkResources true` there, and just leave it in the modules.

Comment: Feature in Instant App will be turned in APK. So it's an APK and not library. That's why it is weird that AS complaints that `shrinkResources` can't be used.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Then, to me it seems like a bug, agree. I'll keep an eye to the one you've already opened.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. this is really working.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is not and AndroidStudio bug, but a Gradle bug.
I'm trying to build with Jenkins, with an updated version of Gradle (previousely used com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3, upgraded it to com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1) and I still get the error

"> Resource shrinker cannot be used for libraries."

Comment: If you have different problem, Can you ask as question and file a bug to Google and  then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Answer (score 1):

**With Reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65708840)**

The fix will be in [3.2 canary 1](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html?utm_source=android-studio) and afterwards release.

I just tried it again on **3.2 canary 3** and it was working. Are you sure you updated the plugin version to `3.2.0-alpha03`? It's easy to overlook.

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65708840) they will re-open to examine.