# shrinkResources is not working dynamic feature module android

Tags: android, dynamic, bundle

I am using the dynamic feature bundles everything working fine but when I set the `shrinkResources true` in the base module.

I am getting the following error

```
Resource shrinker cannot be used for multi-apk applications
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220507/1574250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It looks like the support for resources shrinker is not available for dynamic feature yet. [Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/scope/VariantScopeImpl.java#373)

Comment: I am using 'apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah it looks like the support is not available yet. I updated my answer.